# How to create table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

** I've created table in oracle but getting following error:
**ORA-00903: invalid table name**
**

```
CREATE TABLE user
(id INT NOTNULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(45) NOTNULL,
email VARCHAR(45) NOTNULL,
password VARCHAR(45) NOTNULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Comment: not null <>NOTNULL

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm (USER is a reserved word)

Answer (score 2):

A few things to correct here

- USER is reserved
- NOTNULL
- primary definition
- autoincrment
- varchar2 is preferred over varchar

but you'll end up with something like

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE users
  2  (id      INT         generated as identity NOT NULL ,
  3  name     VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  4  email    VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  5  password VARCHAR2(45) NOT NULL,
  6  constraint users_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
  7  );

Table created.
```

Also checkout quicksql.oracle.com which lets you type in metadata and it generates the table definitions for you. A great way to get started

Comment: In Oracle we use [`varchar2`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-0DC7FFAA-F03F-4448-8487-F2592496A510): *Do not use the VARCHAR data type. Use the VARCHAR2 data type instead.* Although, it is *scheduled to be redefined* for decades, is is clearly said in documentation not to use `varchar`. So it is not few things to correct, but need to rewrite all the `create` statement or better read a single documentation page or at least some example in the first line of Google search results

Comment: I had copied above query but still it generate and error : missing right parenthesis

Comment: Thanks @astentx. I didn't even notice the original varchar when I cut/pasted. Fixed answer

Comment: @shivshah are you possibly running an older version? eg 11g?  Identity column support came in 12c